# Capacitor reactance with frequency variation

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits

Consider that I have a capacitor and resistance connected in series, and I have a voltage source $V_0 \cos(\omega t)$ or some alternating source of voltage connected.

I do understand that the reactance varies with frequency in fact it decreases as frequency increases.

But what really happens inside the capacitor as the frequency changes? Do the charges move between the plates more rapidly or less rapidly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum charge on the capacitor is determined by the amplitude of the applied voltage, but at a higher frequency it comes and goes more rapidly.  More rapid charge movement means more current and less reactance.